# Repetir Datos en un Arreglo

Tags: php, json, mvc

Estoy utilizando `PHP` y cuento con un arreglo que me muestra lo siguiente:

```
0:{clave: "GTO", id: "45", nombre: "Guanajuato"}
1:{clave: "MEX", id: "76", nombre: "México"}
2:{clave: "EUA", id: "54", nombre: "Estados Unidos"}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que me repita los datos que tengo en el, y que en el nuevo arreglo quede de la siguiente manera:

```
0:{clave: "GTO", id: "45", nombre: "Guanajuato"}
1:{clave: "GTO", id: "45", nombre: "Guanajuato"}
2:{clave: "MEX", id: "76", nombre: "México"}
3:{clave: "MEX", id: "76", nombre: "México"}
4:{clave: "EUA", id: "54", nombre: "Estados Unidos"}
5:{clave: "EUA", id: "54", nombre: "Estados Unidos"}
```

Los datos los obtengo desde `Base de Datos`,  utilizo `MVC`, `PHP`, `codeigniter`, `MySQL`

Alguien que me puede ayudar¿?, se le agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje estas utilizando? El arreglo que mencionas no es un JSON, más parece JavaScript. Tienes que mejorar tu pregunta ya que no das mucho detalle para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Estoy utilizando `php` con `codeigniter`, y desde mi controlador mando el arreglo en formato  `JSON`  

`echo json_encode($this->datos_model->lugar());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo sencillo que clona un JSON usando JSON Y otra usando JQUERY, espero te sirva. El codigo va comentado para mejor entendimiento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {

    //clonar usando JSON
    function fnCloneJSON (obj) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }

    //clonar usando jQuery
    function fnClonejQuery (arr) {
        return $.extend(true, [], arr);
    }

//ejemplo de un formato JSON
var list = [{x:2, y:3}, {x:5, y:8}];

//clonamos
var clone1 = fnCloneJSON(list),
clone2 = fnClonejQuery(list);
//aqui concatenamos
var nuevo = clone1.concat(clone2);
console.log("Este es nuevo:", nuevo);

})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```